# java apache poi: how to pass string value to cell formula

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am facing one issue when setting cell formula when a string is passed. I am getting below error. I dont know how to fix this error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'Edelweiss' does not exist in the current workbook.**

Below is the code snipped. String sFcmName can be anything. I just coded to show the example.

```
String sFcmName = "Edelweiss";
cell = currentRow.createCell(iTrialExpiration, CellType.STRING);
sCellFormula = "IF(B"+iRow+"="+sFcmName+",J"+iRow+"-1,J"+iRow+"+F$7-1)";
cell.setCellFormula(sCellFormula);
cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
```

I even tried the below code. but it gave me some different error.

**org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Parse error near char 7 ''' in specified formula 'IF(B21='Edelweiss',J21-1,J21+F$7-1)'. Expected number, string, defined name, or data table**

This is the below code

```
String sFcmName = "Edelweiss";
cell = currentRow.createCell(iTrialExpiration, CellType.STRING);
sCellFormula = "IF(B"+iRow+"='"+sFcmName+"',J"+iRow+"-1,J"+iRow+"+F$7-1)";
cell.setCellFormula(sCellFormula);
cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
```

Comment: I have the impression that you need to quote with double quotes. So the first attempt is wrong because `sFcmName` is unquoted. In the second attmept, replace single quotes with double: `sCellFormula = "IF(B"+iRow+"=\""+sFcmName+"\",J"+iRow+"-1,J"+iRow+"+F$7-1)";`

Comment: Set the formula you want in Microsoft Excel, save the file, read it back in Apache POI, and see how Excel likes to have it formatted?